# Why I can click outside the button's width in my HTML and CSS code?

Tags: html, css

I am struggling to fix a problem in my HTML code, so I made a nice looking button using div command, class attribute and editing it in CSS, but the problem is I can click outside the width of the button, and it works, it opens the link, I can't see the button, I mean I can see it but it's width 300px not long as the screen, any help will be appreciated, thanks.

**Here's the HTML code just in case needed.**

```
<a href="https://youtu.be/rMLzeRghtvY">
        <div class="rb">
            <h3>
                Razer Blade 14
            </h3>
        </div>
    </a>
```

**Here's the CSS code.**

```
.rb {
    margin-top: 50px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: black;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    transition: 0.25s;
    border-style: inset;
    border-color: #00ff00;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 800px;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.rb:hover {
    background-color: #222222;
    transition: 0.25s;
    border-color: #00cc00;
}

h3 {
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 72px; color: #00ff00;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I tried making a button that will take me to an youtube link when clicking it, but the problem is I can click outside the width of the button, for the height it's fine, I can only click inside the height of the button but the clickable width is really long but the visual width is just 800px.

Answer (score 0):

If you make a parent the flex item, you'll lose the click issue.

```css
.makeflex{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.rb {
    margin-top: 50px;        
    height: 200px;
    background-color: black;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    transition: 0.25s;
    border-style: inset;
    border-color: #00ff00;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 800px;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.rb:hover {
    background-color: #222222;
    transition: 0.25s;
    border-color: #00cc00;
}

h3 {
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 72px; color: #00ff00;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="makeflex">
<a href="https://youtu.be/rMLzeRghtvY">
        <div class="rb">
            <h3>
                Razer Blade 14
            </h3>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what your issue is. Are you asking why the entire `div` is an active link when you have the `div` inside the `a` anchor? Maybe you want the anchor to be only inside the `h3`?

```css
.rb {
    margin-top: 50px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: black;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    transition: 0.25s;
    border-style: inset;
    border-color: #00ff00;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 800px;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.rb:hover {
    background-color: #222222;
    transition: 0.25s;
    border-color: #00cc00;
}

h3 {
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 72px; color: #00ff00;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="rb">
  <a href="#">Razer Blade 14</a>
</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```css
.rb {
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h3 {
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 72px;
  margin: 0;
}


.rb a {
  display: block;
  background: black;
  line-height: 44px;
  padding: 75px;
  border: 3px solid #00ff00;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  color: #0f0;
  text-decoration: 1px underline #551a8b;
  transition: 0.25s;
}

.rb a:hover {
  background-color: #222222;
  border-color: #00cc00;
}
```

```html
<div class="rb">
<h3>
<a href="https://youtu.be/rMLzeRghtvY">
        
            
                Razer Blade 14
            
        
    </a>
    </h3>
</div>
```